# How do I create a jQuery Mobile button from javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to make jQuery Mobile render a javascript-generated link as a button widget, like it does automatically when loading the page?

I have javascript like this to create the link dynamically:

```
var ws=document.getElementById('workspace'); // empty <div id="workspace"></div>
ws.innerHTML='<a id="myb" href="foo.php" data-role="button">baz</a>';
```

And of course it only generates a normal link instead of a button, so my question is how do I make jQueryMobile create the button dynamically, as it would have done if the same `<a id="myb" href="foo.php" data-role="button">baz</a>` had appeared in the page from the beginning?

**EDIT :**

A script like this:

```
$('#tagspace').html('<a id="myb" data-inline="true" data-ajax="false"
                    href="boo.php" data-role="button">baz</a>')
              .button()
              .click(function() { window.location.href=this.href;});
```

Is an improvement. It *does* result in a button (full page width), and that is sensitive to clicks outside of the text of the label. However, `this` doesn't seem to be mapped to the  element containing the intended link "destination".

The DOM results of this:

```
<div aria-disabled="false" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-fullsize
                                      ui-btn-block ui-btn-up-c" data-mini="false" data-inline="false" data-theme="c" data-iconpos="" data-icon="" data-wrapperels="span" data-iconshadow="true" data-shadow="true" data-corners="true"> <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">baz</span>
</span>
    <div aria-disabled="false" class="ui-btn-hidden" id="tagspace"> <a id="myb" data-inline="true" data-ajax="false" href="boo.php" data-role="button">baz</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

So, it is still not the same kind of button.

Comment: Why dont you use jquery mobile

Comment: @al0neevenings, how do you suggest that I do it with jquery mobile?

Comment: @Matt, what is `this` mapped to in the `click` handler?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I don't know what `this` is, but it doesn't seem to have a `href` property, since a click on the sensitive part of the button leads to "undefined", which is not the intended page. Of course I could set it to the real URL instead of `this.href` in the click function, but it's still not the same kind of button. Too big, and not clickable where the text is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a button widget by wrapping your element in a jQuery object and calling the `button()` method.

```
$("#workspace").html("<a id='myb' href='foo.php' data-role='button'>baz</a>")
               .button();
```

*Update:* The button widget prevents the default behavior of the link, so you will have to add a `click` handler if you want that behavior back:

```
$("#workspace").html("<a id='myb' href='foo.php' data-role='button'>baz</a>")
               .button()
               .click(function() {
                   window.location.href = this.href;
               });
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the answer I was looking for!
BTW, is there a reason you use single quotes around the attribute values and not the other way around?

Comment: @Matt, that's personal preference. The two languages I use the most both often have single quotes inside sentences, so I prefer double quotes around strings. You can safely disregard that :)

Comment: Ah, that's because links turned into buttons do not navigate to their original `href`. This is by design. I'll update my answer with a workaround.

Comment: Accepting this, because it's the only answer and close enough.